# How do I create a full size background image with no CSS?

Tags: html

How do I create a full size background image with no CSS?

I don't care if the background attribute is deprecated or not, I want to use it.

If I use the plain attribute, however, the image is tiled, not scaled.

Comment: can you please post a minimal reproducible example of the html that you are using?

Comment: Can you please share why you don't want to use css?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The background attribute you want to use was superseded by CSS before the capability to scale background images was added.

There is no, obsolete or otherwise, HTML-only mechanism for scaling background images.

You can't even fake it with a foreground image because you'd need CSS to position it in the background.